# Windows Phone 8 - ScrollViewer max content size, app crashes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, crash, grid, scrollviewer

I am creating game for WP 8 and I am using ScrollViewer and Grid with Buttons for game board.

The problem is when game board is too lardge. Then application crashes with no exception.

Output is:

```
ScrollViewer content size: 2400,2400 //my debug output
The program '[3420] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -528909961 (0xe0797977).
```

Here is XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentPanelScroll" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid x:Name="GamePanel" ShowGridLines="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                    <!-- more RowDefinitions in this grid are addend in C# code-->                               
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <!-- more ColumnDefinitions in this grid are addend in C# code-->                       
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="..."/>
                <!-- more buttons in this grid are addend in C# code-->
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

This is how I resize/zoom game board

```
private void ZoomGameBoard(double delta)
    {
    // typically delta = 10px;
    // 20 columns and 20 rows, each zoomed to 150px is 3000x3000 px
    foreach (var item in RowDefinitions)
    {
        var value = item.Height.Value + delta;
        item.Height = new GridLength(value); // make row bigger so its content stretch
    }

    foreach (var item in ColumnDefinitions)
    {
        var value = item.Width.Value + delta;
        item.Width = new GridLength(value); // make column bigger so its content stretch
    }
}
```

Could you please tell me where is the problem or how to make larger game board?

Thx. :-)

EDIT:

My problem is probably this:

```
Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
```

and this

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
```

But this exception is not thrown every time app craches (just sometimes) does not solve my problem how to display large game board.

EDIT 2:
Here is test application to demonstrate my problem. You can change size in code or use Buttons in bottom part of phone.

Whole project is here: http://www.stud.fit.vutbr.cz/~xmarec12/shared/2013/TestGameApp.zip

[image: Test app img]

Comment: Nothing in what you have shown should cause that type of crash. How are you modifying this control in the code behind? Maybe something there is incorrect.

Comment: Here is code to make game board bigger. Edit in original post.      

private void ZoomGameBoard(double delta)

{

 // typically delta = 10px;

 // 20 columns and 20 rows, each zoomed to 150px is 3000x3000 px

 foreach (var item in RowDefinitions)

 {
  var value = item.Height.Value + delta;
  item.Height = new GridLength(value); // make row bigger so its content stretch
 }

 foreach (var item in ColumnDefinitions)
 {
  var value = item.Width.Value + delta;
  item.Width = new GridLength(value); // make column bigger so its content stretch
 }
}

Comment: Do you really just use `RowDefinitions` and not `GamePanel.RowDefinitions`? If so, that's an issue and it shouldn't even compile. Barring that, your code worked just fine for me with 20 rows, 20 columns, and resizing up to a few thousand pixels per row/column.

Comment: This private method s in class extended from Grid class. So I can use just RowDefinitions. And it works fine... till it is not too large (more that +-2500px)

Comment: So the code you posted is not the code that you use? I don't see any controls inherited from `Grid` there. Either way, this may not be related to the size, because like I said I can get to very very large sizes relative to what you're posting.

Comment: I have edit my post. You can now download test project where the problem occures. If you click on "Zoom IN" button like 15 times, or make grid too bigger, app probably crashes.

Comment: I'll try this out when I'm home and give you some feedback.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.... On my phone and emulator this does not crash, even after zooming in 25-30 times.